# How to connect with mysql of external server to generate reports in Pentaho

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I want to generate reports with an external database of mysql.

Not my localhost database.

I want to generate report of mysql database of external server.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever used the Data Source Wizard?

1. From the Pentaho User Console, select File -> New -> Data Source.
2. Name the new data source.
3. Select "Database Table(s)" as the type.
4. Click the little plus circle to add a database connection.
5. Select the database type. Fill in host name, port, login information, and any other options. Test it if you like.
6. Hit Ok.
7. Continue with Data Source Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

In order for MySQL remote access to work properly, the following needs to happen:

You have to make sure that MySQL is utilizing TCP bind on top of socket binding. Also the address it is binding to has to be accessible outside the machine (ie. not localhost)

A user needs to be created with the proper hostname and database access. DO NOT USE THE ROOT USER.

**OR**

You have to connect to MySQL through an SSH tunnel, if it is bound to localhost on the system, and a user needs to be created with access to the database (you shouldn't use root).

If you're not sure how to do this, I recommend you talk with your systems admin, or if this is hosted on another location, your hosting provider. In general I use the secondary option, but it's also the more difficult to setup for some users.